# Jquery: Calculated Value not showing in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a total amateur with jQuery/Javascript, but I needed to build this calculator and after using many tutorials, code snippets and sample code from this website, I have gotten my script to where it needs to be, except for one very mind boggling fault.

The calculator is meant to simply calculate length x width of 1 or more rooms resulting in a total, which then gets added together into one final total. The twist is that rooms can be added on as required.

After 5 days of reading posts, and scratching the net, I have gotten almost everything working, except for one little problem, and that is the **added row total** is not showing in the Input Field. It does get calculated, and the Value of the input field changes to the total value, but the html does not display it.

Can anyone assist with figuring out why the html value only displays on the first row and not on the dynamically added rows?

My HTML

```
<div id="calculatorModal">
<table id="calctable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Length:</th>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>Width:</th>
            <th>=</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="calculator-row calculator-row-template" id="calculator-row-1">
            <td><input name="length" id="length" class="length-input"></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td><input name="width" id="width" class="width-input"></td>
            <td>=</td>
            <td><input name="totalsqmeters" class="total-output" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">Final Total:   </td>
            <td><input id="alltotal" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="cloneRow()">Add Row</a>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$('#calculatorModal table tbody').on('keyup', 'tr.calculator-row input', function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr.calculator-row').attr('id');
    calculateRow(id);
});

function floor (length, width) {
    return length * width;
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('totalsqmeters');
    var tot=0;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById('alltotal').value = tot;
}

function calculateRow(id) {
    var rowTotal = 0;
    var list = $('#calculatorModal table tbody');
    var rowid = '#' + id;

    var lengthIn = $(rowid + ' .length-input').val();
    var widthIn = $(rowid + ' .width-input').val();

    rowTotal = floor(lengthIn, widthIn);

    $(rowid + ' .total-output').attr('value', rowTotal).append("#calctable");

    calculateTotal();
}

function cloneRow () {
    var i = $('.calculator-row').length + 1;
    var newRowId = 'calculator-row-' + i;

    rowTemplate = $("#calculatorModal table tbody tr:first").clone();

    var newRow = rowTemplate.clone().attr('id', newRowId);

    newRow.find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    }).end().appendTo("#calctable");
}
</script>
```

Here is a codepen of my script: https://codepen.io/RonaldMathuray/pen/JWZLzL

Comment: Quick question. What is the mentioned in bold text "added row total" because I can not find any such thing in the code?

Comment: And which "input field" out of the 4 input fields is this mentioned "added row total" supposed to display in?

Comment: Hmmm on the codepenblahblah your code does not calculate 2nd room added. On my localhost the code you have in this question do work as I think it is expected to work. It is calculating room 1 and room 2 and it sums the total of both rooms. If you are coding in codepenblahblah I would suggest you stop doing it :D No idea what it is though.

Comment: See it yourself here [link](http://goliax.com/working.jpg)

Comment: If this is the result expected I would suggest you use a different jquery version because I do not see where elese your issue might be.

Comment: Hi Jack. The bold text was just to emphasis that it works on the 1st Row, but not on the rows that get added after that.

Comment: Check the link I give you. The code works fine so it must be the jquery version where you have been developing it.

Comment: Hi Jack, I dont code in Codepen, just used it to illustrate my code. I just tried your suggestion of using a later jQuery version, but still no luck. It still isn't showing me the total for the 2nd row or any other added rows. What could be different in your Localhost?

Comment: I just tried uploading the script to my live host account and still no luck. Here is the Link: http://proofs.mediadigital.co.za/tfd/calc.html

Comment: Hmmm it turned out it is not the jquery version as I just uploaded it on my server and it does not work there. I will have to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry it does work online. I did some changes and forget about them. See it here [link](http://goliax.com/test.php) which brings me back to the jquery version so I will explain in a minute where to get my version from and try with it.

Comment: So... make a copy of your current jquery in use and save it somewhere but keep the file in use where it is. Now open this link where my jquery version is located and copy the whole code [link](http://goliax.com/jquery.min.js). After you copy it open your jquery version in use and empty the file replacing the code with the one you just copied which is version 1.7.2 as you can see the first line of the page.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for this I copied your Jquery version, and it works. But any idea why?

Comment: What was your version?

Comment: Btw I would appreciate if you mark the answer I just post as the right answer to the question. Underneath the up and down arrows you have a small icon to do so.

Comment: My original version was: jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: Thank you for marking my answer as the right answer. So what happens is your version is old - just like my PHP version on my server because of which the code developed for facebook registration on my website from another developer does not work exactly as expected. In both your and my case the old version of the programming language does not have yet developed some function or something which your code have.

Comment: But my version was newer than yours, and I even tried it with Jquery 2.1.4 and it didn't work. So why only with Jquery 1.7.2? This is too weird.

Comment: Oh sorry you are right. In this case it is the other way around. Something is deprecated (out of use) in the version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your jQuery version with mine as it works well with it [jQuery 1.7.2](https://goliax.com/jquery.min.js)